# OSError: S con la libreia pybluez de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Estoy intentando conectar un modulo HC-05(esta conectado en mi arduino) a python pero sale el error, mi codigo de pytho es este:

```
 import bluetooth

 bd_addr = "FB:A9:9G:00:0D:32"
 port = 1
 data = "Hola mundo"
 sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
 sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
 sock.send(data)
 sock.close()
```

Tengo la version 3.6 de python, pero al no estar la libreria pybluez para esa version creé un entorno en anaconda desde su prompt.

Aqui el error completo:

```
File "prueba.py", line 9, in <module>
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\proyectob\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", 
line 84, in connect
bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError: S
```

Comment: ¿Como obtuviste el puerto y la dirección?

Comment: Obtuve la dirección con un script de python y el puerto se puede colocar cualquiera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto frustrarme pude lograrlo por así decirlo, para todos los que tengan este problema,

Para empezar el error que arrojo es por el sistema operativo, en foros leí que la librería pybluez solo funcionaba par windows xp,vista,7,8 y 8.1. Yo tengo windows 10

Lo primero que hice fue descargar vmware, ya que a diferencia de virtual box, este tiene drivers para conectar bluetooth con la maquina virtual de una manera sencilla.

Descarguen cualquier iso de los S.O que mencione e instalen la maquina virtual(vmware lo hace por ti)

Una vez instalada tu maquina virtual puedes emparejar cualquier dispositivo bluetooth, le descargas una version de python de 2.7 a 3.5, recomiendo la 3.5, una vez hecho esto descargan la libreria en el siguiente link: 
     https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez (descargaran un archico .whl, solo con poner pip install "nombredelarchivo.whl") y listo.

Ejecutan el primer código que publique, sin embargo tiene un bug ya que aparecerá el error de OS, pero si lo ejecutan varias veces les funcionara, sera un poco tedioso estar ejecutándolo pero tengan perseverancia, para saber que esta funcionando puede agregar un print("Enviado!").

Y listo, no funcionara de la forma mas optima, pero espero poder ayudarles, si alguien encontró otra solución por favor díganmelo. Saludos